# SigmaJS - "sigma is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

Alright, I admittedly feel pretty silly about this one.

I'm just trying out SigmaJS for the first time, and I'm just trying to play around with the library to see what I can do. I am just trying to follow the basic example found on [sigmajs.org](http://sigmajs.org/) under 'tutorial'.

However, I keep getting an error, "sigma is not defined". Any idea why that is happening?  I have my JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/KateJean/068uf9Ly/).

```
// Add a method to the graph model that returns an
// object with every neighbors of a node inside:
sigma.classes.graph.addMethod('neighbors', function(nodeId) {
  var k,
      neighbors = {},
      index = this.allNeighborsIndex[nodeId] || {};

  for (k in index)
    neighbors[k] = this.nodesIndex[k];

  return neighbors;
});

sigma.parsers.gexf(
  'les-miserables.gexf',
  {
    container: 'sigma-container'
  },
  function(s) {
    // We first need to save the original colors of our
    // nodes and edges, like this:
    s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
      n.originalColor = n.color;
    });
    s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
      e.originalColor = e.color;
    });

    // When a node is clicked, we check for each node
    // if it is a neighbor of the clicked one. If not,
    // we set its color as grey, and else, it takes its
    // original color.
    // We do the same for the edges, and we only keep
    // edges that have both extremities colored.
    s.bind('clickNode', function(e) {
      var nodeId = e.data.node.id,
          toKeep = s.graph.neighbors(nodeId);
      toKeep[nodeId] = e.data.node;

      s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
        if (toKeep[n.id])
          n.color = n.originalColor;
        else
          n.color = '#eee';
      });

      s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
        if (toKeep[e.source] && toKeep[e.target])
          e.color = e.originalColor;
        else
          e.color = '#eee';
      });

      // Since the data has been modified, we need to
      // call the refresh method to make the colors
      // update effective.
      s.refresh();
    });

    // When the stage is clicked, we just color each
    // node and edge with its original color.
    s.bind('clickStage', function(e) {
      s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
        n.color = n.originalColor;
      });

      s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
        e.color = e.originalColor;
      });

      // Same as in the previous event:
      s.refresh();
    });
  }
);
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it was two things:

1. My sources were not being recognized for some reason. (error on sigma not being defined)
2. Firefox was having no trouble displaying the graph -- Chrome was. I'll need to look into why Chrome is not working well with SigmaJS.

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/KateJean/068uf9Ly/
** Open in Firefox.

```
    sigma.parsers.gexf(
  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jacomyal/sigmajs.org/master/assets/data/les-miserables.gexf',
  {
    container: 'sigma-container'
  },
```